# UIStoryboardSegue animates property in subclass

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard

I have a `UIStoryboardSegue` subclass for replacing current view controller with next view controller.

As we have a `Animates` property in interface editor, I want to access this property in the subclass.

[image]

My code is following:

```
class ReplaceSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        var viewControllers = source.navigationController?.viewControllers.dropLast() ?? []
        viewControllers.append(destination)
        source.navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers.map {$0}, animated: true) // I dont want this `true` to be hardcoded
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the answer posted below lemme know if it helps :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari It's working, thanks. :)

Comment: Am glad it did :) happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments in `UIStoryBoardSegue` class

> The segue runtime will call +[UIView setAnimationsAreEnabled:] prior
>   to invoking this method, based on the value of the Animates checkbox
>   in the Properties Inspector for the segue.

So obviously you can read the value of animate check box by using

```
UIView.areAnimationsEnabled
```

So in my custom segue

```
class MySegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        debugPrint(UIView.areAnimationsEnabled)
    }
}
```

This prints `false` if animate checkbox is `unchecked` or `true` if it is `checked` :)

So in your case

```
class ReplaceSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
            var viewControllers = source.navigationController?.viewControllers.dropLast() ?? []
            viewControllers.append(destination)
            source.navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers.map {$0}, animated: UIView.areAnimationsEnabled)
    }
}
```

I hope whats happening is already clear, incase you still have doubt, here is the explanation, iOS checks the animates checkbox value and uses it to set whether animations are enabled or not by calling `setAnimationsAreEnabled` with the value of animates check box in interface prior to calling `perform()` method.

So when the control reaches inside perform you can be assured that iOS has already read the value of animates check box and used it to set `setAnimationsAreEnabled` all you have to do now is to ask `areAnimationsEnabled` to get the value of animates check box.

So that should provide you the value of animates checkbox :)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a `UIStoryboardSegue` subclass for this. [The docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboardsegue?language=objc) state "You can subclass `UIStoryboardSegue` in situations where you want to provide a custom transition between view controllers". This means that a replacement without without any animation isn't a custom transition, thus shouldn't use a segue subclass.

The correct way to do replacement is to use a Show Detail (e.g. Replace) segue and inside the parent view controller that is managing the child view controllers implement the method `showDetailViewController` and replace the children, e.g.

```
@implementation DetailNavigationController

- (void)showDetailViewController:(UIViewController *)vc sender:(id)sender{
    [self setViewControllers:@[vc] animated:NO];
}
```

If you didn't know, the Show Detail segue (after magically instantiating the destination view controller) has a perform method that just calls `showDetailViewController` on self, and the base `UIViewController` implementation searches up the view controller hierarchy looking for one that overrides `showDetailViewController`, so you can intercept it and perform your custom code, before say it goes up to another parent that might implement it also like a split view.